# Pyspark dataframe write parquet without deleting /_temporary folder

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df.write.mode("append").parquet(path)
```

I'm using this to write parquet files to an S3 location. It seems like in order to write the files, it's also creating a `/_temporary` directory and deleting it after use. So I got access denied. Admin on our AWS account doesn't want to grant the code delete permission on that folder.

I proposed to write the files to another folder where delete permission can be granted then copy the files over. But Admin still wants me to write files directly to the destination folder.

Is there certain configuration I can set to ask Pyspark don't do the deletion on the temporary directory?

Comment: How are you running this on AWS. What's the name of the service

Comment: I'm using AWS EMR

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such option for `_temporary` folder.

But if you're running your Spark job on EMR cluster, you can write first to local HDFS of your cluster and then copy data to S3 using Hadoop `FileUtil.copy` function.

On Pyspark, you can access this function via JVM gateway like this :

```
sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil
```